# Garage ceiling - reinsulate/drywall

Tags: hvac, drywall, framing

My master shower leaked through to my garage; we've pulled all the garage ceiling drywall and installation anywhere the moisture meter read wet.  Since, my plumber has repaired the leak, but before I patch up the ceiling I wanted to wait a few weeks to really make sure the leak was sourced.

In the exposed ceiling, there is an HVAC register and a couple inches of tubing that is exposed, and since it gets into the 90 degrees in my garage, I've noticed the register is condensing and even dripping onto the garage floor.  Is there anything special I should do prior to making the repair?  Will a R30- faced batt be enough to keep the condensation at bay?  I intend to stop the A/C, dry out the register with a fan and towels in the few hours before I actually make the repair to the ceiling.  A friend mentioned adding spray foam around the register before putting the fiberglass up.  Pictures attached.

thank you all in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything "special" you have to do. However, having said that, there are a few things I would consider doing:

1. I agree with your friend that using spray foam insulation is a good idea on the metal.
2. I would consider installing an access panel in case the problem reoccurs in the future.
3. I would try to move the wire away from the joist to minimize the risk of a nail or drywall screw inadvertently hitting it during the patch repair or after wards.

R-30 faced should be fine.

Comment: Wiring is _supposed_ to be run _along_  joists, not left free floating in the space between them. It should, however, be stapled to the joist at about 1/2 chord to minimize the chance of a screw/nail penetrating it. It should _not_ be running _under_ that cross bracing. If the wire were attached to the center of that joist, someone would have to use a stupidly over-long fastener to risk hitting it.